# Configure SpringBoot PropertyNamingStrategy only for deserialization in Jackson?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I wonder if it's possible to configure Jackson in Spring Boot to use different
`PropertyNamingStrategy` only for deserialization?

I know that it's possible to configure a global setting in properties e.g.:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

Is it possible to do it only when deserializing?

Comment: I think yes. Have a look at DeserializationConfig of Jackson

Comment: @SimonMartinelli but I believe it's not possible to configure in properties?

Comment: No you can't configure this with properties. You have to configure the ObjectMapper in a @Bean factory method